How to identify which element to scrape when using read_html?
Trying to pull data from the main table on this URL , but read_html pulls from a table hidden in the dropdown menu at the top of the page instead. this URL
I tried specifying the table number, but it just gave me the headers without any of the actual data:
url <- "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/major-league?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&season=2024&season1=2024&ind=0&qual=1&pageitems=2000000000&v_cr=202301&type=c%2C7%2C31%2C13%2C16%2C24%2C19%2C15%2C212&month=0"
page <- read_html(url)
player_stats <- html_table(html_nodes(page, "table"))[[10]]
player_stats
# A tibble: 0 × 11
# … with 11 variables: # <lgl>, Name <lgl>, Team <lgl>, GG - Games Pitched <lgl>, PitchesPitches - Pitches Thrown <lgl>, IPIP - Innings Pitched <lgl>, RR - Runs Allowed <lgl>, SOSO - Strikeouts <lgl>, BBBB - Walks <lgl>, HH - Hits Allowed <lgl>, RA9-WARRA9-WAR - Wins Above Replacement calculated using Runs Allowed <lgl>
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names

I think the real solution is to use xpath to specify exactly where on the page I'm trying to pull from, but I'm not really sure how to do that. I popped open developer tools, but I don't see a table ID and am wondering if there is some other element I could use.

Choosing the [[10]]th element is a bit arbitrary, and while you might see 9 tables before it on the HTML page, the order you see is not always the same, and there are often embedded components not visible (for many reasons). I suggest [[10]] is not the best way to go.
While it is usually best to pick a table by an ID or some other unambiguous attribute, sometimes we have to resort to finding a known attribute about the table, such as a column name.
Looking at all tables,
page_static <- read_html(url)
html_nodes(page_static, "table")
# {xml_nodeset (10)}
#  [1] <table class="menu-scores-table"><tbody><tr>\n<td>\n<div class="menu-sub-header">AL Games</div>\n<table><tbody></tbody></table>\n</td>\n<td class="menu-ta ...
#  [2] <table><tbody></tbody></table>
#  [3] <table><tbody></tbody></table>
#  [4] <table class="menu-standings-table"><tbody><tr>\n<td>\n<div class="menu-sub-header">AL East</div>\n<div id="menu-standings-ale"><div></div></div>\n<div cl ...
#  [5] <table class="menu-team-table"><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td>\n<div class="menu-sub-header">AL East</div>\n<a href="//www.fangraphs.com/teams/blue-jays">Blue Jays</a ...
#  [6] <table class="menu-team-table"><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td>\n<div class="menu-sub-header">AL East</div>\n<a href="//www.fangraphs.com/roster-resource/depth-charts/ ...
#  [7] <table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td class="team-box_link__inactive__24Fnd">BAL</td>\n<td><a href="https://blogs.fangraphs.com/chicago-white-sox-top-27-prospects">CH ...
#  [8] <table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td class="team-box_link__inactive__24Fnd">ATL</td>\n<td><a class="team-box_state__prelim__jxGiG" href="https://blogs.fangraphs.com/ ...
#  [9] <table>\n<thead><tr>\n<th class="th-rank fixed">#</th>\n<th data-col="0" data-col-id="Name" data-stat="Name" class="align-left  fixed ">Name</th>\n<th dat ...
# [10] <table>\n<thead><tr>\n<th class="th-rank fixed">#</th>\n<th data-col="0" data-col-id="Name" data-stat="Name" class="align-left  fixed ">Name</th>\n<th dat ...

Nothing stands out ... let's explore what each table looks like:
html_nodes(page_static, "table") |>
  lapply(html_table)
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 3
#   X1       X2    X3      
#   <chr>    <lgl> <chr>   
# 1 AL Games NA    NL Games
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 0 × 0
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 0 × 0
# [[4]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 3
#   X1                       X2    X3                      
#   <chr>                    <lgl> <chr>                   
# 1 AL EastAL CentralAL West NA    NL EastNL CentralNL West
# [[5]]
# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#   X1                                                                           X2                                                                            X3   
#   <chr>                                                                        <chr>                                                                         <chr>
# 1 AL EastBlue Jays  |  DCOrioles  |  DCRays  |  DCRed Sox  |  DCYankees  |  DC AL CentralGuardians  |  DCRoyals  |  DCTigers  |  DCTwins  |  DCWhite Sox  |… AL W…
# 2 NL EastBraves  |  DCMarlins  |  DCMets  |  DCNationals  |  DCPhillies  |  DC NL CentralBrewers  |  DCCardinals  |  DCCubs  |  DCPirates  |  DCReds  |  DC  NL W…
# [[6]]
# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#   X1                                        X2                                            X3                                         
#   <chr>                                     <chr>                                         <chr>                                      
# 1 AL EastBlue JaysOriolesRaysRed SoxYankees AL CentralGuardiansRoyalsTigersTwinsWhite Sox AL WestAngelsAstrosAthleticsMarinersRangers
# 2 NL EastBravesMarlinsMetsNationalsPhillies NL CentralBrewersCardinalsCubsPiratesReds     NL WestD-backsDodgersGiantsPadresRockies   
# [[7]]
# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#   X1    X2    X3   
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 BAL   CHW   LAA  
# 2 BOS   CLE   OAK  
# 3 NYY   DET   SEA  
# 4 TBR   KCR   TEX  
# 5 TOR   MIN   HOU  
# [[8]]
# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#   X1    X2    X3   
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 ATL   CHC*  ARI  
# 2 MIA   CIN   COL  
# 3 WSN   MIL   LAD  
# 4 NYM*  PIT   SDP* 
# 5 PHI   STL   SFG  
# [[9]]
# # A tibble: 0 × 11
# # ℹ 11 variables: # <lgl>, Name <lgl>, Team <lgl>, GG - Games Pitched <lgl>, PitchesPitches - Pitches Thrown <lgl>, IPIP - Innings Pitched <lgl>,
# #   RR - Runs Allowed <lgl>, SOSO - Strikeouts <lgl>, BBBB - Walks <lgl>, HH - Hits Allowed <lgl>,
# #   RA9-WARRA9-WAR - Wins Above Replacement calculated using Runs Allowed <lgl>
# [[10]]
# # A tibble: 0 × 11
# # ℹ 11 variables: # <lgl>, Name <lgl>, Team <lgl>, GG - Games Pitched <lgl>, PitchesPitches - Pitches Thrown <lgl>, IPIP - Innings Pitched <lgl>,
# #   RR - Runs Allowed <lgl>, SOSO - Strikeouts <lgl>, BBBB - Walks <lgl>, HH - Hits Allowed <lgl>,
# #   RA9-WARRA9-WAR - Wins Above Replacement calculated using Runs Allowed <lgl>

Yup, I see the "10th" youi're hoping to get (could be 9th?), but clearly it's empty. First, I don't see an id= or such that clearly breaks those two out from the other tables. Second, it is empty, suggesting that the data is filled in by javascript.
Fortunately, rvest_1.0.4 adds rvest::read_html_live which uses a headless Chrome (some OS components might be needed?) that allows the javascript components to work so that you can harvest your necessary data.
I'll use that, and suggest a way to dynamically get the table(s) you want.
page_dynamic <- read_html_live(url)
html_nodes(page_dynamic, "table")
# {xml_nodeset (16)}
#  [1] <table class="menu-scores-table"><tbody><tr>\n<td>\n<div class="menu-sub-header">AL Games</div>\n<table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="https://www.fangraphs. ...
#  [2] <table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="https://www.fangraphs.com/livewins.aspx?date=2024-04-05&amp;team=Yankees&amp;dh=0&amp;season=2024">TOR (3) @ NYY (0)</a ...
#  [3] <table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="https://www.fangraphs.com/livewins.aspx?date=2024-04-05&amp;team=Cubs&amp;dh=0&amp;season=2024">LAD (7) @ CHC (9)</a></ ...
#  [4] <table class="menu-standings-table"><tbody><tr>\n<td>\n<div class="menu-sub-header">AL East</div>\n<div id="menu-standings-ale"><table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td> ...
#  [5] <table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&amp;stats=bat&amp;lg=all&amp;qual=0&amp;type=8&amp;season=2024&amp;month ...
#  [6] <table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&amp;stats=bat&amp;lg=all&amp;qual=0&amp;type=8&amp;season=2024&amp;month ...
#  [7] <table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&amp;stats=bat&amp;lg=all&amp;qual=0&amp;type=8&amp;season=2024&amp;month ...
#  [8] <table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&amp;stats=bat&amp;lg=all&amp;qual=0&amp;type=8&amp;season=2024&amp;month ...
#  [9] <table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&amp;stats=bat&amp;lg=all&amp;qual=0&amp;type=8&amp;season=2024&amp;month ...
# [10] <table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td><a href="https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&amp;stats=bat&amp;lg=all&amp;qual=0&amp;type=8&amp;season=2024&amp;month ...
# [11] <table class="menu-team-table"><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td>\n<div class="menu-sub-header">AL East</div>\n<a href="//www.fangraphs.com/teams/blue-jays">Blue Jays</a ...
# [12] <table class="menu-team-table"><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td>\n<div class="menu-sub-header">AL East</div>\n<a href="//www.fangraphs.com/roster-resource/depth-charts/ ...
# [13] <table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td class="team-box_link__inactive__24Fnd">BAL</td>\n<td><a href="https://blogs.fangraphs.com/chicago-white-sox-top-27-prospects">CH ...
# [14] <table><tbody>\n<tr>\n<td class="team-box_link__inactive__24Fnd">ATL</td>\n<td><a class="team-box_state__prelim__jxGiG" href="https://blogs.fangraphs.com/ ...
# [15] <table>\n<thead><tr>\n<th class="th-rank fixed">#</th>\n<th data-col="0" data-col-id="Name" data-stat="Name" class="align-left  fixed ">Name</th>\n<th dat ...
# [16] <table>\n<thead><tr>\n<th class="th-rank fixed">#</th>\n<th data-col="0" data-col-id="Name" data-stat="Name" class="align-left  fixed ">Name</th>\n<th dat ...

Okay, so many more tables. If we did the |> lapply(html_table) trick I used above, we'll see that the data is actually filled in this time. Looking at those tables, only two of them have column names "Name" and "Team" (among the others), so let's filter on those to retrieve your data.
my_tables <- html_nodes(page_dynamic, "table") |>
  lapply(html_table) |>
  Filter(\(tb) "Name" %in% names(tb), x = _)
my_tables
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 409 × 11
#      `#` Name  Team  `GG - Games Pitched` PitchesPitches - Pit…¹ IPIP - Innings Pitch…² `RR - Runs Allowed` `SOSO - Strikeouts` `BBBB - Walks` `HH - Hits Allowed`
#    <int> <chr> <chr>                <int>                  <int>                  <dbl>               <int>               <int>          <int>               <int>
#  1     1 Shan… CLE                      2                    166                   12                     0                  20              1                  10
#  2     2 Brad… KCR                      2                    171                   13.1                   1                  14              2                   5
#  3     3 Cris… HOU                      2                    187                   11                     0                   9              6                   5
#  4     4 Fran… CIN                      2                    181                   11.2                   1                   9              3                   9
#  5     5 Seth… KCR                      2                    172                   12.2                   1                   7              3                  10
#  6     6 Rone… HOU                      1                    106                    9                     0                   7              2                   0
#  7     7 Zac … ARI                      2                    186                   11                     1                   9              5                   6
#  8     8 Merr… ARI                      2                    170                   13.2                   3                  12              1                   8
#  9     9 Jord… SFG                      2                    172                   12                     2                  11              1                   8
# 10    10 Garr… CHW                      2                    180                   13                     2                  16              1                   8
# # ℹ 399 more rows
# # ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​`PitchesPitches - Pitches Thrown`, ²​`IPIP - Innings Pitched`
# # ℹ 1 more variable: `RA9-WARRA9-WAR - Wins Above Replacement calculated using Runs Allowed` <dbl>
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 409 × 11
#      `#` Name  Team  `GG - Games Pitched` PitchesPitches - Pit…¹ IPIP - Innings Pitch…² `RR - Runs Allowed` `SOSO - Strikeouts` `BBBB - Walks` `HH - Hits Allowed`
#    <int> <chr> <chr>                <int>                  <int>                  <dbl>               <int>               <int>          <int>               <int>
#  1     1 Shan… CLE                      2                    166                   12                     0                  20              1                  10
#  2     2 Brad… KCR                      2                    171                   13.1                   1                  14              2                   5
#  3     3 Cris… HOU                      2                    187                   11                     0                   9              6                   5
#  4     4 Fran… CIN                      2                    181                   11.2                   1                   9              3                   9
#  5     5 Seth… KCR                      2                    172                   12.2                   1                   7              3                  10
#  6     6 Rone… HOU                      1                    106                    9                     0                   7              2                   0
#  7     7 Zac … ARI                      2                    186                   11                     1                   9              5                   6
#  8     8 Merr… ARI                      2                    170                   13.2                   3                  12              1                   8
#  9     9 Jord… SFG                      2                    172                   12                     2                  11              1                   8
# 10    10 Garr… CHW                      2                    180                   13                     2                  16              1                   8
# # ℹ 399 more rows
# # ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​`PitchesPitches - Pitches Thrown`, ²​`IPIP - Innings Pitched`
# # ℹ 1 more variable: `RA9-WARRA9-WAR - Wins Above Replacement calculated using Runs Allowed` <dbl>
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

In this case, it just-so-happens that both tables are identical (which seems odd ... why have two identical tables in HTML? shrug), but there may be conditions under which they differ. I'll leave that exploration to you.
FYI, Hadley Wickham (author of rvest) recently mentioned on LinkedIn:

Just put up the notes for a recent talk (APIs with httr2) and workshop (web scraping with rvest) on github: (two redacted shorturls). The rvest workshop contains new material on scraping dynamic websites and some techniques for finding unofficial/undocumented APIs that you can parse with jsonlite #rstats

Those two short-urls (prohibited by the Stack interface) resolve to
https://github.com/hadley/talk-httr2 and https://github.com/hadley/web-scraping, the latter includes some artifacts of the "live" portion.

Thank you! This is extremely helpful. Only thing is when I run this, I'm getting:
Unhandled promise error: Chromote: timed out waiting for response to command Page.navigate
Error: Chromote: timed out waiting for event Page.loadEventFired

I got that too the first time I tried read_html_live(), it self-resolved a few minutes later. I suggest calling it again, perhaps it's caused by unrelated (and unreproducible) network pauses, server-isms, etc. If it repeats, perhaps it's OS related. Either way, rvest::read_html_live() is new to me as well so I don't know how best to troubleshoot it.

Were you able to get past that error, @AaronWood?

To complete r2evans's answer, you have other options.
Packages :
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

Option 1 : using dynamic version of the website with an appropriate XPath to select the table
Sys.setenv(
  CHROMOTE_CHROME = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
)

url="https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/major-league?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&season=2024&season1=2024&ind=0&qual=1&pageitems=2000000000&v_cr=202301&type=c%2C7%2C31%2C13%2C16%2C24%2C19%2C15%2C212&month=0"
dyn=read_html_live(url)

output = html_elements(dyn,xpath = '//div[@class="table-scroll"]/table') %>%
  html_table() %>%
  flatten_df()

Output :
# A tibble: 414 × 11
     `#` Name            Team  `GG - Games Pitched` PitchesPitches - Pitc…¹ IPIP - Innings Pitch…² `RR - Runs Allowed` `SOSO - Strikeouts`
   <int> <chr>           <chr>                <int>                   <int>                  <dbl>               <int>               <int>
 1     1 Ronel Blanco    HOU                      2                     196                   15                     0                  11
 2     2 Paul Blackburn  OAK                      2                     173                   13                     0                   7
 3     3 Tanner Houck    BOS                      2                     182                   12                     0                  17
 4     4 Shane Bieber    CLE                      2                     166                   12                     0                  20
 5     5 Brady Singer    KCR                      2                     171                   13.1                   1                  14
 6     6 Cristian Javier HOU                      2                     187                   11                     0                   9
 7     7 Frankie Montas  CIN                      2                     181                   11.2                   1                   9
 8     8 Seth Lugo       KCR                      2                     172                   12.2                   1                   7
 9     9 Shota Imanaga   CHC                      2                     137                   10                     0                  12
10    10 Garrett Crochet CHW                      3                     257                   18                     4                  21
# ℹ 404 more rows
# ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​`PitchesPitches - Pitches Thrown`, ²​`IPIP - Innings Pitched`
# ℹ 3 more variables: `BBBB - Walks` <int>, `HH - Hits Allowed` <int>,
#   `RA9-WARRA9-WAR - Wins Above Replacement calculated using Runs Allowed` <dbl>

Option 2 : using the JSON file which contains the data
json=fromJSON("https://www.fangraphs.com/api/leaders/major-league/data?age=&pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=1&season=2024&season1=2024&startdate=2024-03-01&enddate=2024-11-01&month=0&hand=&team=0&pageitems=2000000000&pagenum=1&ind=0&rost=0&players=&type=c%2C7%2C31%2C13%2C16%2C24%2C19%2C15%2C212&postseason=&sortdir=default&sortstat=RA9-Wins")
df=json$data

output=df %>% select(PlayerName,TeamName,G,Pitches,IP,R,SO,BB,H,`RA9-Wins`) %>%
  mutate(`RA9-Wins`=round(`RA9-Wins`,digits = 1)) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "#") %>% 
  setNames(c("#","Name","Team","G","Pitches","IP","R","SO","BB","H","RA9-WAR")) %>%
  arrange(desc(`RA9-WAR`)) %>% 
  as_tibble()

Output :
# A tibble: 414 × 11
   `#`   Name            Team      G Pitches    IP     R    SO    BB     H `RA9-WAR`
   <chr> <chr>           <chr> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 1     Ronel Blanco    HOU       2     196  15       0    11     6     1       1.2
 2 2     Paul Blackburn  OAK       2     173  13       0     7     1     6       1  
 3 3     Tanner Houck    BOS       2     182  12       0    17     2     7       0.9
 4 4     Shane Bieber    CLE       2     166  12       0    20     1    10       0.8
 5 5     Brady Singer    KCR       2     171  13.1     1    14     2     5       0.8
 6 6     Cristian Javier HOU       2     187  11       0     9     6     5       0.8
 7 7     Frankie Montas  CIN       2     181  11.2     1     9     3     9       0.8
 8 8     Seth Lugo       KCR       2     172  12.2     1     7     3    10       0.8
 9 9     Shota Imanaga   CHC       2     137  10       0    12     0     4       0.8
10 10    Garrett Crochet CHW       3     257  18       4    21     1    11       0.7
# ℹ 404 more rows

Option 3 : using the legacy version of the website
### We need 4 tables to get all the data (Pitches, RA9-WAR,...)
urls=c(t1="https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders-legacy.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=1&type=8&season=2024&month=1000&season1=2024&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2024-03-01&enddate=2024-11-01&page=1_1000",
       t2="https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders-legacy.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=1&type=6&season=2024&month=1000&season1=2024&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2024-03-01&enddate=2024-11-01&page=1_1000",
       t3="https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders-legacy.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=1&type=2&season=2024&month=1000&season1=2024&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2024-03-01&enddate=2024-11-01&page=1_1000",
       t4="https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders-legacy.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=1&type=0&season=2024&month=1000&season1=2024&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2024-03-01&enddate=2024-11-01&page=1_1000")

### Declaring the columns names we need
cols=list(c("Name","Team","G","IP"),"RA9-WAR","Pitches",c("R","SO","BB","H"))

### Declaring the function to construct the tables
pitches=function(x,y){
    sortiez=html_element(read_html(x),xpath = "//span[@style='white-space: nowrap;']//table")%>%
    html_table() %>% 
    setNames(unlist(.[2,])) %>%
    slice(-c(1:3)) %>% 
    arrange(Name,Team) %>% 
    select(all_of(y))
}

### Map operation
tables=map2(urls,cols,pitches)

### Binding of the tables. Results are sorted by "RA9-WAR" (descending).
### Since RA9-WAR values are rounded, rows might appear in a slightly different order than displayed on the "dynamic" website
output=bind_cols(tables) %>% 
  select(c("Name","Team","G","Pitches","IP","R","SO","BB","H","RA9-WAR")) %>%
  arrange(desc(`RA9-WAR`)) %>% 
  mutate(`#`=row_number(),.before=1,
         across(c(4:11),~as.numeric(.x)))

Output :
# A tibble: 414 × 11
     `#` Name            Team  G     Pitches    IP     R    SO    BB     H `RA9-WAR`
   <dbl> <chr>           <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1 Ronel Blanco    HOU   2         196  15       0    11     6     1       1.2
 2     2 Paul Blackburn  OAK   2         173  13       0     7     1     6       1  
 3     3 Tanner Houck    BOS   2         182  12       0    17     2     7       0.9
 4     4 Brady Singer    KCR   2         171  13.1     1    14     2     5       0.8
 5     5 Cristian Javier HOU   2         187  11       0     9     6     5       0.8
 6     6 Frankie Montas  CIN   2         181  11.2     1     9     3     9       0.8
 7     7 Seth Lugo       KCR   2         172  12.2     1     7     3    10       0.8
 8     8 Shane Bieber    CLE   2         166  12       0    20     1    10       0.8
 9     9 Shota Imanaga   CHC   2         137  10       0    12     0     4       0.8
10    10 Garrett Crochet CHW   3         257  18       4    21     1    11       0.7
# ℹ 404 more rows


Probably as implied by @E.Wiest the right thing to do is to use the API to retrieve JSON (or XML?) and not scrape the HTML. Using the CRAN package rjsoncons and the API query to the JSON provided by @E.Wiest, I retrieved the JSON string as
url = "https://www.fangraphs.com/api/leaders/major-league/data?age=&pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=1&season=2024&season1=2024&startdate=2024-03-01&enddate=2024-11-01&month=0&hand=&team=0&pageitems=2000000000&pagenum=1&ind=0&rost=0&players=&type=c%2C7%2C31%2C13%2C16%2C24%2C19%2C15%2C212&postseason=&sortdir=default&sortstat=RA9-Wins"
json <- j_query(url)

and then used j_pivot() to (a) construct a JSON 'array-of-objects' with the fields of interest, and (b) pivot to a tibble
path <- 'data[].{
    PlayerName: PlayerName, 
    TeamName: TeamName, 
    G: G,
    Pitches: Pitches,
    IP: IP,
    R: R,
    SO: SO,
    BB: BB,
    H: H,
    "RA9-Wins": "RA9-Wins"
}'
tbl <- j_pivot(json, path, as = "tibble")

(path is a JMESPath expression, sort of like XPath for JSON).
The result is
# A tibble: 414 × 10
   PlayerName     TeamName     G Pitches    IP     R    SO    BB     H `RA9-Wins`
   <chr>          <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 Ronel Blanco   HOU          2     196  15       0    11     6     1      1.18 
 2 Paul Blackburn OAK          2     173  13       0     7     1     6      0.980
 3 Tanner Houck   BOS          2     182  12       0    17     2     7      0.886
 4 Shane Bieber   CLE          2     166  12       0    20     1    10      0.850
 5 Brady Singer   KCR          2     171  13.1     1    14     2     5      0.833
 6 Cristian Javi… HOU          2     187  11       0     9     6     5      0.792
 7 Frankie Montas CIN          2     181  11.2     1     9     3     9      0.765
 8 Seth Lugo      KCR          2     172  12.2     1     7     3    10      0.765
 9 Shota Imanaga  CHC          2     137  10       0    12     0     4      0.764
10 Garrett Croch… CHW          3     257  18       4    21     1    11      0.703
# ℹ 404 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Actually this could be done directly on the url, j_pivot(url, path, as = "tibble") but it is convenient when developing the path to have a local copy (also for use with, e.g., listviewer::jsonedit()).
